# Calculation of long number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add 1 with **00112014000002000003300008**? I need **00112014000002000003300009** after adding 1.

I am trying to remove first two zeros. My code is like below

```js
var lastrow = $('#lastrow');
var item_no = +lastrow.find('.item_no').text();
    
var item_no_to_increase = item_no.toString().substring(2);
    
console.log(item_no_to_increase);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lastrow">
  <p class="item_no">00112014000002000003300008</p>
</div>
```

I would like to add 1 after removing Zeros. But I am getting console output **12014000002e+23**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you retrieve from the DOM is already a String, but you're coercing it to a Number by using `+` in front of `+lastrow`. Get rid of that `+` and ditch the `.toString()` in `item_no.toString().substring(2);`

For addition, the max number in JavaScript is `9007199254740991`. So you'll have to do some addition on a smaller part of the number and rejoin it as a String.

This is a great article demonstrating how you can work with large numbers:

https://medium.com/@nitinpatel_20236/javascript-adding-extremely-large-numbers-and-extra-long-factorials-229b6055cb1a

There is also this library that does all the heavy lifting for you:

https://github.com/niinpatel/addVeryLargeNumbers

#### Basic Example

This example is a very basic example, and obviously won't work if you add `1` to `9`.

```js
var number = '00112014000002000003300008';

function incrementByOne(number) {
  var start = number.slice(0, number.length -1);
  var end = parseInt(number.slice(number.length -1));
  
  end++;
  
  console.log(start + end);
}

incrementByOne(number);
```

#### Get number from HTML (per comments discussion)

```js
var lastrow = $('#lastrow');
var item_no = lastrow.find('.item_no').text();
console.log(typeof item_no, item_no);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="lastrow">
  <p class="item_no">00112014000002000003300008</p>
</div>
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: Thanks @AnonymousSB. I am collecting the value from a span like this `item_no = +lastrow.find('.item_no').text(); console.log(item_no);`. I getting output at console `1.12014000002e+23`. I would like to get ouput `00112014000002000003300008`.

Comment: @abuabu, what is `+lastrow`, `.find()`, and `.text()`, that's not standard JavaScript, what library are you using?

Comment: I am using jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu Please take a look at my updated answer, I grab the value from the HTML and get the expected string, you need to remove the `+` from your code, as it converts it to a number.